# How to update angular resource urls with id from the authenticated user?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-resource

So I have defined multiple angular factories with ngResource similar to:

```
.factory('factoryName', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'authService', factoryNameCtrl])
function factoryNameCtrl($resource, $http, CONSTANTS, authService) {
    var actions = {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                service: '@service',
                action: '@action'
            }
        },
        'post': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                service: '@service',
                action: '@action'
            }
        }
    }
    actions.get.params.userId = actions.post.params.userId = '@' + authService.currentUser.id;
    var res = $resource(CONSTANTS.baseURL + '/:userId/integrations/:service/:action', {}, actions);
```

If I log in and logout with another user, the value of userId inside the factory doesn't update.

I don't want to pass userId into each params from all over my code, but to make it available when it changes.

Previously I had the code below and I was forcing a page reload to rebuild the correct urls into the resource.

```
if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
        var res = $resource(CONSTANTS.baseURL + '/' + authService.currentUser.id + '/integrations/:service/:action', {}, actions);
        return res;
    }
```

What do you advise to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute it fresh every time, use a function:

```
actions.get.params.userId = function () {
    return computeCurrentUserId();
};
```

From the Docs:

> If a parameter value is a function, **it will be executed every time** when a param value needs to be obtained for a request (unless the param was overridden).

-- [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: I remembered now that I read this long time ago. Thanks, saved me lots of time!